# Need help level shifting

Tags: amplifier, level-shifting

I have an AC signal (500 - 1000Hz) 1v peak to peak that sweeps around 0v. The signal needs to be shifted to 0.5 -2V, a gain of 1.5... The power supply is +-10V. Just looking for someone to point me in the right direction, and if anyone has examples of similar circuits that would be great.

Comment: Just curious, but what does the circuit feed into/drive and what is driving it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEEOfY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To calculate the values, the [TL431](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf) (ref input shorted to anode) needs 1mA to work, so let's
set the current ignoring R3 to about 1.5mA. So R4 ~= 5K, use 4.7K.

The resistor ratio R1/(R2||R3) = 0.5 for a gain of 1.50 so let's arbitrarily set R1 = 10.0K

We know for an input voltage of 0V the output voltage should be 1.25V.

So 1.25V/10K = 2.495V/R3

So R3 = 19.96K, 20.0K is close enough

We also know R2||R3 = 20K, so R2 ~= open.

Go back and check our R4 assumption is okay- worse case is with Vin = +0.5V so
the current through R3 is about 3V/20K = 150uA leaving plenty of margin for D1 to
work.

Although you *could* use the power supply as a reference, usually that's a bad idea because it is less accurate and more noisy than even the cheapest reference (like the TL431). If you want to use the power supply, just re-calculate replacing your negative power supply voltage for the reference voltage.

Note that my example with the TL431 happens to work out to eliminate R2 as a happy coincidence. The implication is that Vref must be <= -2.5V, so you cannot use a reference of (say) -1.25V.